# Javascript Object-Oriented : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate'"

Tags: javascript, oop, three.js

I am starting object-oriented JavaScript programming.
I'm using WebGL to draw a 3d scene on a canvas, and three.js lib to simplify WebGl.

I am having trouble with my object Animator :

```
class Animator
{
    constructor(sceneObjects)
    {
        alert("initiating Animator");
        var _sceneObjects = sceneObjects;
        var _lon = 0, _lat = 0, _phi = 0, _theta = 0;

        this.animate = function()
        {
            requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
            this.update();
        }

        this.update = function()
        {
            _lat = Math.max(-85, Math.min(85, _lat));
            _phi = THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - _lat);
            _theta = THREE.Math.degToRad(_lon);
            _sceneObjects.getCamera().target.x = 500 * Math.sin(_phi) * Math.cos(_theta);
            _sceneObjects.getCamera().target.y = 500 * Math.cos(_phi);
            _sceneObjects.getCamera().target.z = 500 * Math.sin(_phi) * Math.sin(_theta);
            _sceneObjects.getCamera().lookAt(_sceneObjects.getCamera().target);

            // distortion
            //camera.position.copy( camera.target ).negate();

            _sceneObjects.getRenderer().render(_sceneObjects.getScene(), _sceneObjects.getCamera());
        }

        //setters
        this.setLon = function(val) {
            _lon = val;
        }
        this.setLat = function(val) {
            _lat = val;
        }
        this.setPhi = function(val) {
            _phi = val;
        }
        this.setTheta = function(val) {
            _theta = val;
        }
        //getters
        this.getSceneObjects = function() {
            return _sceneObjects;
        }
        this.getLon = function() {
            return _lon;
        }
        this.getLat = function() {
            return _lat;
        }
        this.getPhi = function() {
            return _phi;
        }
        this.getTheta = function() {
            return _theta;
        }
    }
}
```

The function Animator.animate() should draw the image in the canvas, it is given by the Three.js library.
I have already made it work outside of an object. Only, when I call Animator.update() now, this error pops :

```
Animator.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of undefined
    at Animator.animate
```

Why can't I read it ? Any ideas ?
Thank you !

Comment: This error said that you tried to call `something.animate(...)` with that `something` is in fact `undefined`. Can you write the line witch calls to animate function ?

Comment: It seems like you may be trying to access the animate function as if it was a static function `Animator.animate()`, but maybe you have not yet created an instance of Animator? You are also adding all your animator methods within the Animator constructor, so they are not available until you have an instance of Animator (you probably don't want to be adding the methods inside the constructor).